# Amazon AWS Itemsearch - Using Keywords to Search in Product Title Only

Tags: search, amazon-web-services, keyword, amazon-product-api

Does anyone know how to target the Amazon AWS ItemSeach so that it searches in the product title only? I'm using keywords but the results returned are only vaguely related.

This example searches for 'wireless headset xbox' in the 'Accessories' node(676172011) of 'VideoGames':

```
&Operation=ItemSearch
&SearchIndex=VideoGames
&ItemPage=1
&BrowseNode=676172011
&Sort=salesrank
&Keywords=Wireless%20headset%20xbox
&ResponseGroup=Large
```

I would expect this to return only products with 'wireless headset xbox' in the tile.  However only aprroximately 50% are 'correct'.

Looking at the results returned from similar 'aStore' searches, all results have the keyword in the title.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [ItemSearch](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html) documentation you need to replace the `Keywords` parameter with the `Title` parameter:

> **Title** - *The title associated with the item. You can enter all or part
>   of the title. **Title searches are a subset of Keyword searches.** If a
>   Title search yields insufficient results, consider using a Keywords
>   search. [emphasis mine]*

Comment: Steffen Opel - That does the trick.  Thank you so much - you must know the documentation off by heart!!